# laravel check if it exists and send an alert

Tags: php, laravel-blade, laravel-6

I need help with Laravel

I need to get a code that runs:  if and send a message ::

```
 $text = App\Nota::select('nombre')->where('id', 3);
```

I need to check that if a `string = 'hello'` arrives it will print a message in .blade

in short check if it exists and send an alert

Help me please

Comment: And what's your quesiton about this?

Answer (score 0):

you can do in this way.

```
$text = App\Nota::select('nombre')->where('id', 3);if($text->nombre=="hello"){Session::flash('message', 'This is a message!');Session::flash('alert-class', 'alert-danger'); }
```

In the view you can make it display like this.

```
@if(Session::has('message'))<p class="alert {{ Session::get('alert-class', 'alert-info') }}">{{ Session::get('message') }}</p>@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way using `exist()` method if you just want to check record is exists or not. Here, in your case, you just want to check that modal `Nota` having id 3 and it's *nombre* column should be equal to *hello*. There is no need to load the modal, you can try specifying both conditions in `where()` method and use `exist()` to check the record exist.

**Controller**

```php
$exist = App\Nota::where([
    'id' => 3,
    'nombre => 'hello'
])->exists();

if(!$exist){
    Session::flash('message', 'This is a message!'); 
    Session::flash('alert-class', 'alert-danger'); 
}
```

**View**

```php
@if(Session::has('message'))
<p class="alert {{ Session::get('alert-class', 'alert-info') }}">{{ 
    Session::get('message') }}</p>
@endif
```